# How to have One URL which sends to one-of-three Google Forms URLs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I have a need to get equal populations in each of three surveys.  The three surveys are identical except for one change - it contains different pictures.

I would like to distribute a single URL to my survey respondents.

I would like to count the number of previous responses I have, and add one.
I would like to redirect the session to one of three (Google Forms) URLs based upon the calculation

**(Responses.Count + 1) MOD 3**.

I think I need a Google Apps script to do this?

Here is some pseudocode:

```
var form0 = FormApp.openByUrl( 
   'htttps://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/2342f23f1mg/viewform' 
);

var form1 = FormApp.openByUrl( 
   'htttps://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/23422333g/viewform' 
);

var form2 = FormApp.openByUrl( 
   'htttps://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/2342wfeijqeovig/viewform' 
);

var form0Responses = form0.getResponses();
var form1Responses = form1.getResponses();
var form2Responses = form2.getResponses();

var whichURL = (
   form0Responses.length +
   form1Responses.length +
   form2Responses.length + 1
  ) % 3;                     // modulo three

// var goToForm =  switch ( whichURL ) blah blah;
// redirect to goToForm;
// How do I redirect now?
```

Thanks!

Comment: So it looks like you answered your own question. Use a switch and based on the expression set the value of goToForm. Something I am not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a simpler solution possible but I don't think I know of it :)

The common link that you give out could be a link to a "proxy" page that doesn't contain anything but just redirects users to the correct page. Or it could be a link to the actual page with a necessary form embedded. Let's look at the options.

**0) Publish your code as web app**

In either case you'll need to have your code published as a web app. In GAS it's way simpler than it sounds, you'll find all the info here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Make sure you set that `Anyone, even anonymous` can access the app and it always runs as you (if you choose `User accessing the app`, they'll have to go through authentication process which is not what you need here).

**1) Redirect via GAS web app.**

Your code in this case would look like so:

```
// I changed your function a bit so that it could be easier to work with 
// in case the number of your forms changes later on
function getForm() {

  var forms = [
    {
      // I'm using openById instead of openByUrl 'cause I've run into issues with 
      // the latter
      form: FormApp.openById('1')
    },
    {
      form: FormApp.openById('2')
    },
    {
      form: FormApp.openById('3')
    }    
  ];

  var whichURL = 0;
  for (var i in forms) {
    forms[i].responses = forms[i].form.getResponses().length; 
    whichURL += forms[i].responses;
  }
  whichURL++;

  // we're returning the actual URL to which we should redirect the visitors
  return forms[whichURL % forms.length].form.getPublishedUrl();
}

// doGet is Google's reserved name for functions that 
// take care of http get requests to your web app
function doGet() {
  // we're creating an html template from which getForm function is called
  // as the template is evaluated, the returned result 
  // of the function is inserted into it
  // window.open function is a client-side function 
  // that will open the URL passed to it as attribute
  return HtmlService.createTemplate('<script>window.open("<?= getForm() ?>", "_top");</script>').evaluate();
}
```

So, after you've published your app, you'll get the link opening which the `doGet` function will run — and you're going to be redirected to your form.

The thing here is that the URL that you're getting this way is not rather beautiful, sth like https://script.google.com/macros/s/1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/exec and it will also show a message at the top of the page "The app wasn't developed by Google" during those 1-2 seconds before redirect happens.

**2) Embed your form into another webpage**

The idea here is different: instead of giving your users a "proxy" link, you'll provide them with a page that'll ask a Google script for a correct form link and will display that form in the page in an iframe.

So, there are a couple of steps:

**2.1)** Change your `doGet` function (`getForm` will stay the same):

```
function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(getForm());
}
```

In this case `doGet` will not return an html to render by browser but just a link to your form.

*Sidenote:* after changing the code you'll need to publish a new version of your code for the changes to take effect.

**2.2)** Create a Google site at sites.google.com

**2.3)** Insert an "Embed" block into your page, with the following code:

```
<script>
function reqListener(response) {
  // change height and width as needed
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<iframe src="' + response.target.response + '" width="400" height="400"></iframe>'); 
}
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "INSERT-YOUR-SCRIPT-URL");
oReq.send();
</script>
```

What it does: javascript code sends an http request to your script, gets the form URL and passes it on into the callback function, `reqListener` which in turn inserts it into document body within an `iframe` element.

The good thing is that your URL which will be much more user-friendly (you could use this approach on your own site, too).

As a result, you'll have sth like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm terribly impressed by the amount of work you put into this answer.  However, something must be wrong. 

1. I expect that no matter what URL I paste over "INSERT-YOUR-SCRIPT-URL" then I should be able to see that in my frame.  This does not happen.

Comment: 2. I expect that when I browse to my web app url by itself that I should get something.  Instead I get an error, "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 5, file "Code", project "Helping")".

Comment: When I used F12 mode:

<iframe id="userHtmlFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="overflow: auto;">
</iframe>
<html><head><base target="_blank"><script>
function reqListener(response) {
  // change height and width as needed
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<iframe src="' + response.target.response + '" width="80%" height="80%"></iframe>'); 
}
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/blablabla/edit");
oReq.send();
</script></head><body></body></html>
"
"
</iframe>

Comment: 1. No, not really. The second option that I described depends on the fact that your script available at "INSERT-YOUR-SCRIPT-URL" returns your form's URL. 
So it will not actually show the content of the page at "INSERT-YOUR-SCRIPT-URL" on your page.

Comment: 2. My best guess is this error might mean that in your `getForms()` function some invalid form id is used.